# Interesting integral in Probability theory and reference request

Tags: probability, integration, reference-request, proof-explanation

I'm studying "Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes" (4th ed.) by Papoulis and while discussing a coin-tossing example he uses the following integral:

$$ P(A)=\int_{0}^{1} P(A|\vec{p}=p) f_p (p) dp= \int_{0}^{1} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{(n-k)!k!}{(n+1)!}.$$

Now, how did the author compute that integral? I've used WolframAlpha to compute it and the result uses the "hypergeometric function" (which I've never seen in my calculus or analysis courses). Could someone recommend a book/lecture notes to learn how to compute these kinds of integrals (and others like it that may come up in probability and statistics)?

Comment: In probability context, one common technique is to recognize the integrand as one of the common distribution. In this case the integrand is proportional beta pdf, so we can easily write down the result by recognizing the parameters. You may take a look at Beta distribution / Beta Integral / Gamma distribution as well.

Comment: Don't worry ! You will see a lot of them. On the search bar of the site, just type *hypergeometric* : 4467 entries !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be computed using integration by parts and induction on $n-k$ (for fixed $n$).

Suppose $k=n$ so $n-k=0$. Then
$$\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \ dp =\int_0^1 p^n \ dp = \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n!0!}{(n+1)!}= \frac{k!(n-k)!}{(n+1)!}.$$

Now suppose that for some $1 \leq j \leq n-k$, if $n-k=j$ then
$$\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \ dp = \frac{(n-k)!k!}{(n+1)!}.$$
Now let $n-k = j+1$. (Note that $n-(k+1)=j$ and $k+1=n-j$.) Letting $u = (1-p)^{n-k}$ and $dv = p^k\ dp$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \ dp &= (1-p)^{n-k}\frac{p^{k+1}}{k+1}\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1\frac{p^{k+1}}{k+1}(n-k)(1-p)^{n-k-1}(-1) \ dp\\
&=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\int_0^1 p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k+1)} \ dp\\
&= \frac{n-k}{k+1} \cdot \frac{(n-(k+1))!(k+1)!}{(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(n-k)!k!}{(n+1)!} 
\end{align*}
where we used the induction hypothesis in the second-to-last step.

Comment: very clear and helpful: thank you.